# Elasticsearch: Java Client for Composite Aggregation using Terms queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have created a composite query for aggregating on 2 different attributes as below -

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "query": {
                            "script": {
                                "script": {
                                    "source": "params.territoryIds.contains(doc['territoryHierarchy.id'].value) ",
                                    "lang": "painless",
                                    "params": {
                                        "territoryIds": [
                                            12345678
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "boost": 1.0
                            }
                        },
                        "path": "territoryHierarchy",
                        "ignore_unmapped": false,
                        "score_mode": "none",
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "script": {
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "doc['forecastHeaders.id'].value == params.id && doc['forecastHeaders.revenueCategory'].value == params.revenueCategory ",
                                                "lang": "painless",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "revenueCategory": 0,
                                                    "id": 987654321
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "boost": 1.0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": "forecastHeaders",
                                    "ignore_unmapped": false,
                                    "score_mode": "none",
                                    "boost": 1.0
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "nested": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "script": {
                                            "script": {
                                                "source": "doc['forecastHeaders.id'].value == params.id && doc['forecastHeaders.revenueCategory'].value == params.revenueCategory ",
                                                "lang": "painless",
                                                "params": {
                                                    "revenueCategory": 0,
                                                    "id": 987654321
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "boost": 1.0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": "forecastHeaders",
                                    "ignore_unmapped": false,
                                    "score_mode": "none",
                                    "boost": 1.0
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "revnWinProbability": [
                            40,
                            50
                        ],
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "revenueStatus.keyword": [
                            "OPEN"
                        ],
                        "boost": 1.0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "recordUpdateTime":{
                            "gte":1655117440000
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "aggregations": {
        "TopLevelAggregation": {
            "composite" : {
                "size" : 10000,
                "sources" : [
                    {
                        "directs": {
                            "terms": {
                                "script": {
                                    "source": "def territoryNamesList = new ArrayList(); def name; def thLength = params._source.territoryHierarchy.length; for(int i = 0; i< thLength;i++) { def thRecord = params._source.territoryHierarchy[i];  if (params.territoryIds.contains(thRecord.id) && i+params.levelToReturn < thLength) { territoryNamesList.add(params._source.territoryHierarchy[i+params.levelToReturn].name);} } return territoryNamesList;",
                                    "lang": "painless",
                                    "params": {
                                        "territoryIds": [
                                            12345678
                                        ],
                                        "levelToReturn": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "qtr" : {
                            "terms" : {
                                "field" : "quarter.keyword",
                                "missing_bucket" : false,
                                "order" : "asc"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "revnRevenueAmount": {
                    "sum": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "doc['revenueTypeCategory.keyword'].value != 'Other' ? doc['revnRevenueAmount']:doc['revnRevenueAmount']",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        },
                        "value_type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this query does a composite aggregation based on two different terms aggregations, directs and qtr, and it works fine.

Now I am trying to create a corresponding spring data java client implementation for it. So I have created the code as below -

```
BoolQueryBuilder baseQueryBuilder = getQueryBuilder(searchCriteria);

List<TermsAggregationBuilder> aggregationBuilders = getMultiBaseAggregationBuilders(searchCriteria, baseQueryBuilder);
```

Where the bool query supplies the first part of the bool query and the getMultiBaseAggregationBuilders method returns the 2 different terms aggregations shown in the query above - directs and qtr. Now I am not finding any API to send this list of terms aggregations to the composite aggregation builder. Would be really grateful if someone can give me a pointer as to how this list of terms aggregations can be used inside the composite aggregation builder so the same can be achieved in the java code as it shows in the elastic query above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` and using `withQuery()` and `withAggregations`?

Comment: Hello @P.J.Meisch , Thanks so much for your hint. I have used NativeSearchQueryBuilder for some of the other aggregations, but I was not sure how to send composite aggregations through it. Would be grateful if you pl point me to some resource that shows how to do that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: doesn't `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder#withAggregations(java.util.Collection<org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AbstractAggregationBuilder<?>>)` work?

Comment: Hello @P.J.Meisch, if I send a list of abstract aggregation builders, containing 2 terms query builders inside it, to the NativeSearchQueryBuilder class, would they be treated as a composite of those 2 terms queries, or do I need to specify something that quantifies these terms queries to be treated as a composite? Please let me know your advice on that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello @P.J.Meisch , Code samples as below always use CompositeAggregationBuilder to create the composite agg clauses. Not getting how that translates to when we just pass a list of AbstractAggregationBuilders. Does it still do composite? - 

`NativeSearchQueryBuilder qb = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder(); 
List<CompositeValuesSourceBuilder<?>> src=new ArrayList<>(); 
src.add(new TermsValuesSourceBuilder(“firstLetter”).field(“firstLetter.keyword”));  CompositeAggregationBuilder agg = AggregationBuilders.composite(“firstLetterAgg”, src).size(200);  qb.addAggregation(agg);`

Comment: Hello @P.J.Meisch, I just tried passing the two terms as below -

`NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withIndices(indexName).withQuery(baseQueryBuilder);
for (AbstractAggregationBuilder aggBuilder : aggregationBuilders) queryBuilder.addAggregation(aggBuilder);`

The aggregations get applied in two different groups and do not get a composite one as shown below - 

`“aggregations”: {“MyDirectsAggregation”: {“terms”: {..}
    “QtrAggregation”: {“terms”: {..}}`

Comment: There is a `CompositeAggregationBuilder` as well, do you use that? Btw, this is not a problem with Spring Data Elasticsearch but with the native Elasticsearch components you build

Comment: Thanks so much for your guidance, @P.J.Meisch . The abstract aggregation builder routine that creates the terms aggs is deep inside the class hierarchy in my code, and so thought I could get an array of these terms aggs, and then add them to a composite. As it looks like, I do not have a method in NativeSearchQueryBuilder that would let me add individual terms aggs in something like `queryBuilder.addComposite(List<AbstractAggregationBuilder>)`. So probably I would create a subroutine for composite and add the terms to composite as they get created, & then send the composite back. Thanks a lot